# How exactly works this simple PrimeNG Angular 2 example?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, javascript-framework

I am very new in **Angular 2\4** (I came from Java) and I have the following doubts about an Angular project that uses **PrimeNG** "components".

I followed this quick "Hello World" video tutorial (it seems to me an official tutorial) to create my first example that includes **PrimeNG** into my Angular 4 webapp: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Nvze0dhzkE

I have some doubts about the logic of this example and about how eventually I can refactor this.

Ok as you can see it is putting these line:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value"></p-calendar>
{{value | date:'dd.mm.yyyy'}}
```

related to the **PrimeNG** calendar component (I think that it is a component, because from what I know the custom tag are associated to component, is it? correct me if I am doing wrong assertion).

I think that I have not the code of this component but is something that I have downloaded with npm and should be into the **node_modules** directory of my project, is it?

Then it was modified the **app.module.ts** file in this way:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CalendarModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

// ???
export class MyModel {
  value: Date;
}
```

My doubts are mainly related to this class declared into this **app.module.ts** file:

export class MyModel {
      value: Date;
    }

It seems to me useless, I tried to remove and my project still works.

So what exactly does this line in my view?

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value"></p-calendar>
```

I think that it should put the value inserted by the user into the **value** field of the previous **MyModel** class, but seems that I am missing something and doesn't works in this way. What am I missing?

Another doubt is, can I do something like this:

- Create a custom component that will be used as a custom tag into my **app.component.html** view, something like **MyCustomCalendar** associated to a  tag.
- This component view should contain the
- Its controller should contain a variable that will be initialized using the selected date.

Can I do something like this?

Comment: Do you have a `value` property in `AppComponent`? Or the only `value` property you have is inside `MyModel` class?

Comment: @Szabolcs the only value is into MyModel class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to answer a few of your questions, but it's a bit hard without seeing the whole code:

> I think that it is a component, because from what I know the custom tag are associated to component, is it?

Correct - It is a component

> I think that I have not the code of this component but is something that I have downloaded with npm and should be into the node_modules directory of my project, is it?

Correct - You have probably done something like

```
npm install primeng --save
```

This downloads the whole primeng ui-suite into your `node_modules` folder. In Angular, multiple parts of an application are bundled into one module. In your app.module.ts you are importing the primeng `CalendarModule` from your node_modules folder. The module does also contain the component which you referred to before (the calender-component which is related to the selector `<p-calendar>`)

> So what exactly does this line in my view?

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value"></p-calendar>
```

It creates the p-calender component at this part of your html. The [(ngModel)] binds the `value` property in your component to the p-calendar component. **The value property must exist within the component which your html belongs to**. You are using two-way-binding here. Meaning, when your value changes, p-calendar will be notified about it. When p-calender changes the value, the value inside your component will change as well.

- Two-way-binding uses the banana-in-a-box syntax --> `[(ngModel)]=`...
- One way binding uses only brackets --> `[ngModel]=`...

> Another doubt is, [...] Can I do something like this?

Yes. You should read more tutorials or videos about angular and read the official docs. It's hard to explain this here.

Comment: Ok, so it means that the p-calendar component contain a variable named value?

Comment: Yes. This is sort of the interface to use this component.

Comment: @AndreaNobili `p-calendar` may contain a variable named `value` but when you do `[(ngModel)]="value"` you are doing two-way-binding to the parent component's `value` property, in this case `AppComponent`. Otherwise you couldn't access `{{ value }}` in your template.

Comment: The strange thing is that I have not a value property in my AppComponent

Comment: It seems like `[(ngModel)]` dynamically creates the variable you are assigning it to inside your template, when it doesn't find it in your component.